# normal distribution probability coding

Tags: probability, mean, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I would like to code the following question, 
   " Cost to operate a FedEx Canada commercial airplane from Toronto to Montreal follows the normal distribution with a mean of $5000 per hour and a standard deviaton of $200. Compute the operating cost for the lowest 4% of the airplane

my code is:

> > > pnorm(0.04, mean = 5000, sd = 200, lower.tail=TRUE)

but the answer does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

The pnorm() function is calculating the cumulative probability of the price (which is essentially the "complementary error function", erfc()), but I think you want the inverse of this function, i.e. that price below which the prices occur with a probability of 4%. In R, that can be computed with qnorm() (which is essentially the inverse of the complementary error function). There's a helpful discussion of these functions on [Sean Kross](http://seankross.com/notes/dpqr/)' website.